# selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list. Previous ans did not solve

Tags: c#

i have string which needs slash as a requirement.

```
string FolderAndNotebook = "TC_301509_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMdd-
hhmmss") + "_Folder_/TC_301509_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMdd-hhmmss");
```

The string is not throwing any run time exception. 
But when i try to send the string as an argument. It throws an exception as mentioned in the title.

Usage done by the above string, mentioned below.

```
string notebookName = Pane.CreateNewNotebook(FolderAndNotebook);
```

I tried

```
string FolderAndNotebook = "TC_301509_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMdd-
hhmmss") + @"/TC_301509_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMdd-hhmmss");
```

and

```
string FolderAndNotebook = "TC_301509_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMdd-
hhmmss") + @"//TC_301509_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMdd-hhmmss");
```

When i debug the code, i revisited the method from catch by forcing the debug point to that method. The test passes. But when i try to run the code. The above exception is raised.

Comment: Removed Selenium tag since this has nothing to do with Selenium. Print `FolderAndNotebook` right after it's created... what does it print? What does the code for `CreateNewNotebook()` look like?

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and ["How much research effort is expected?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you.